# “ng build –env=prod” command not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, build

I've been given a JavaScript website and need to rebuild it to incorporate changes I've made to it.

I was told to run the following command from the source files directory in order to build the application:

```
ng build –env=prod
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.

I have angular-cli 0.1.0, node 4.2.2 and npm 2.14.7 installed, and am on Windows using Git Bash, if any of that helps.

If anyone has any ideas about why this is happening that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are probably in the wrong directoy. Go navigate to your project's root first

Answer (score 1):

First make sure, you are in project directory which you are building for production. If not got to dir by `cd PROJECT_DIR`

once you are in directory, try `ng build --prod` its equivalent to what you are using or try `ng build --target=production --environment=prod`

Hope this helps.